# Gimp selected area coordinates with python

Tags: python, coordinates, gimp

I want to get selected area px coordinates of an image. I use gimp and can i see that on the python fu console as real time debugging ?

I'm planning to free select some area on picture and i want to learn it on console. Which coordinates are in that selected area ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, when in Python concole, you have to geta  reference to the working image - the easier way to get that is to call gimp.image_list()  - this present you with a list of the open images in the reversed order they appear on the tabs in the "single window" mode. So, to get the last oppened image, you can type:

```
 image = gimp.image_list()[0]
```

(and press `<enter>`)
If you type "image" and presse , you will inspect its contents - Python will display the standard representation of an Image object: 
`<gimp.Image '[Untitled]'>`  - now, this image object, and its layers (which Pyton exposes in the  as a list on the `image.layers` attribute)  can be passed as parameters to hundreds of functions you can easily search if you press the `browse` button on the bottom of the dialog. After finding the wanted method, just click on `apply` on the PDB browsing dialog, and the function and its needed parameters will be pasted on the Python prompt  -if needed, edit the parameters to fit your needs, and call it by pressing ; In this case you want to call ("gimp_get_selection_bounds"):

```
>>> non_empty, x1, y1, x2, y2 = pdb.gimp_selection_bounds(image)
```

And your wanted values are now in the variables x1, y1, x2 and y2. If you want just to display them, delete the command up to the `pdb` and the returned values will be just printed.

If you will work on this often, it will be seriously usefull to learn a little of Python - the tutorial on the http://python.org site will be able to help you a lot.

Comment: This is working but didn't help me. This give me only coordinates of endpoints. I need all of the coorsinates in that selection.

Comment: So, take my advice on "learning Python" - sorry, I can't really answer that in a single answer, not knowing even if you are aquainted with programming or not.  If you type  `selection = image.selection.get_pixel_rgn(0, 0, image.width, image.height)`  you will get a 2D array of all pixels on the selection - all the ones with non-zero value are part of the selection.